# Probability sampling with or without replacement

Tags: probability

There are $8$ green balls, $4$ blue balls and $3$ white balls in a box. Then $1$ green and $1$ blue balls are taken from the box and put away. What is the probability that a blue ball is selected at random from the box?

Comment: Hi! What have you tried?

Comment: Have tried using the sampling without replacement method am just not getting it

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Observe that once you remove $1$ green ball and $1$ blue ball from the box, you are left with $7$ green balls, $3$ blue balls, and $3$ white balls in the box.  How many ways can you select a blue ball from the box?  How many ways can you select a ball from the box?